# Select the last 4 posts of the site on the main page

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to display the last 4 articles of the last site on the main page in a concise way. I have made a model view and I only have a problem with ef core.

ViewModel:

```
public class ShowBlogForHomePageViewModel
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string BlogTitle { get; set; }
        public string BlogUrl { get; set; }
        public string BlogImageName { get; set; }
        public string MetaDescriptionBlog { get; set; }
    }
```

IBlogService:

```
List<ShowBlogForHomePageViewModel> GetBlogPostForHome();
```

BlogService:

```
  public List<ShowBlogForHomePageViewModel> GetBlogPostForHome()
        {
            var ListBlogs= _context.Blogs.OrderByDescending(b => new ShowBlogForHomePageViewModel()
            {
                BlogId = b.BlogId,
                BlogImageName = b.BlogImageName,
                BlogTitle = b.BlogTitle,
                MetaDescriptionBlog = b.MetaDescriptionBlog,
                BlogUrl = b.BlogUrl 
            }).Take(4).ToList();
            return null;
        }
```

I think this part is true . please check it:

```
public List<ShowBlogForHomePageViewModel> GetBlogPostForHome()
        {
            return _context.Blogs.OrderBy(b=>b.BlogId).Select(b => new ShowBlogForHomePageViewModel()
            {
                BlogId = b.BlogId,
                BlogImageName = b.BlogImageName,
                BlogTitle = b.BlogTitle,
                MetaDescriptionBlog = b.MetaDescriptionBlog,
                BlogUrl = b.BlogTitle
            }).TakeLast(4).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: You say you have a problem, but you don't describe what the problem is. What is the code doing wrong? Are you getting an error? What is it doing differently from what you desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public List<ShowBlogForHomePageViewModel> GetBlogPostForHome()
        {
            return  _context.Blogs
            .OrderByDescending(b => b.BlogId)
           .Select(b => new ShowBlogForHomePageViewModel
            {
                BlogId = b.BlogId,
                BlogImageName = b.BlogImageName,
                BlogTitle = b.BlogTitle,
                MetaDescriptionBlog = b.MetaDescriptionBlog,
                BlogUrl = b.BlogUrl 
            }).Take(4)
              .ToList();
            
        }
```

Comment: thanks Sergey. Post updated .please check it. I thinks its true